# Can I use mtouch to build a library?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I want to build a dll from all my package dependencies using mtouch. I have tried different options and failed.
Giving the root-assembly as my dll plus all packages gives me `MT0052: No command specified`

Answer (score 0):

I think mtouch can not do that . From doc of **[Using mtouch to Bundle Xamarin.iOS Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/mtouch)** , you can see :

> The process of turning a `.NET` executable into an application is mostly driven by the mtouch command, a tool that integrates many of the steps required to turn the application into a bundle. This tool is also used to launch your application in the simulator and to deploy the software to an actual iPhone or iPod Touch device.

It just transfers a existed `.NET` executable into an application ,can not help you bind library into an application .

You also can see the **[COMPILATION MODE](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=man%3Amtouch(1))** doc of mtouch , there are four mode :

- **--abi=ABI**
  Comma-separated list of ABIs to target. Currently supported: armv6, armv6+llvm, armv7, armv7+llvm, armv7+llvm+thumb2, armv7s, armv7s+llvm, armv7s+llvm+thumb2. Fat binaries are automatically created if more than one ABI is targetted.
  To use the LLVM optimizing compiler code generation backend instead of Mono's default code generation backend target one of the llvm ABIs. Build times take considerably longer for native code, but the generated code is shorter and performs better.

You may also instruct the LLVM code generator to produce ARM Thumb instructions by targetting one of the llvm+thumb2 targets. Thumb instructions produce more compact executables.

- **--cxx**
  Enables C++ support. This is required if you are linking with some third party libraries that use the C++ runtime. With this flag, mtouch uses the C++ compiler to drive the compilation process instead of the C compiler.
- **-sim=DIRECTORY**
  This compiles the program and assemblies passed on the command line into the specified directory for use with the iOS simulator. This generates a standalone program that is entirely driven by the C# or ECMA CIL code.
- **-dev=DIRECTORY**
  This compiles the program and assemblies passed on the command line into the specified directory for use on an iPod Touch, iPhone or iPad device. The target directory can be used as the contents of a .app directory This generates a standalone program that is entirely driven by the C# or ECMA CIL code.

**mtouch** not supports binding library , it just compiles a existed executable which already binded library .

By the way , if want to bind a third party library , official doc recommands you to use **[Binding iOS Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/)** .

Comment: I understood that part from the doc. However iOS apps do not allow dynamic code and and mtouch does load all relevant code into the final binary, so it's linker does do something similar. I tried using mono linker independently but can't figure out how to just make a static dll.

Comment: @Rohit Sorry for not understanding why need to make a static dll ,iOS has its way to bind library .